# sql error that i cant solve (7)

Tags: mysql, sql

can anyone help with this error , when i run my code it comes up with error 1005 can't create table my code looks like this can anyone point out the source of this error im using codio mysql if that helps

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries (
    entries_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    students_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
    subjects_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entries_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (students_id) REFERENCES students(students_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subjects_id) REFERENCES subjects(subjects_id));
```

this is the error 
mysql> SOURCE task7
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'exams.entries' (errno: 150)

Comment: please add which database engine? I assume it's mysql, but please update the question

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` gives more info about the error

Comment: Edit your question an include the error.  One possibility is that the foreign key references are not declared as primary keys.

Comment: You should provide some logs. My guess, for sure tabels students and subjects have INT UNSIGNED as primary key ?

Comment: You've got to be kidding me with the way you posed this question.  It is utterly unhelpful and will not enrich the knowledge base here.  Edit the subject line to describe the challenge.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

This error related to foreign keys. Check following items:

- Name of tables and columns that exist on foreign keys are correct.
- Type of foreign keys columns are same.
- Data of foreign keys not conflict with them.

Note: You can disable check foreign key on query. Sure enable this option after query.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries (
  entries_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  students_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  Date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
  subjects_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (entries_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (students_id) REFERENCES students(students_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (subjects_id) REFERENCES subjects(subjects_id)
);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: i tried running this code two rows were affected but it still shows up with a error 1005

Comment: Please share sql schema for **students** and **subjects** tables in your question. @malicefulchalice

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is related with the foreign keys (as removing them creates the table with no errors).
Main possible causes:

- One of the referenced tables doesn't exists
- The field of the referenced tables doesn't exists
- The data types of the referenced table doesn't match (I assume is this).

As i can see your primary key on your table is INT, assuming you use INT as your primary keys, students_id is INT UNSIGNED, possibly the cause of your error.